# Getting error while connecting to MongoDB through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting the following error while connecting to the MongoDB through Node.js.

> Error:

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: connect UNKNOWN 127.0.0.1:27017 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at connect (net.js:843:14)
    at net.js:939:9
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

I am running the my MongoDB using the command `mongod --dbpath C:\new --journal`.I am explaining my code below.

```
var mongo=require('mongojs');
var database='medilink';
var collections=['admin','supplier'];
var db=mongo("localhost:27017/"+database, collections);
```

Here i have one login app.When user is trying to  login the above error is coming.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you start mongodb before this code run ?

Comment: Yes,Please read my post again.But still its not coming.

Comment: I think, mongodb is terminating for its old lock file. You can try to repair this.

Comment: Command : 
Step 1: Remove lock file.
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

Step 2: Repair mongodb. 
sudo mongod --repair 

Step 3: start mongodb.
sudo start mongodb 
or
sudo service mongodb start

Step 4: Check status of mongodb.
sudo status mongodb 
or   
sudo service mongodb status

Step 5: Start mongo console.
mongo

Comment: I have already followed this steps before but did not get any proper output.BTW i am using windows so sudo is not allowed.

Comment: Check if anything else is using port 27017. Perhaps it is another instance of your own code. Also check if anything is listening on this port with `netstat -a`. It must be `mongodb` server.

Comment: @Thevs : Yes,you were right.The ip address was different for this port `27017`.I put that ip in my code but still the same error is coming.